# CSS How to make scrollable list fading

Tags: css

I want to create a list of elements that fade out at the top and bottom as i scroll that list.
The example is on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Girafa/vttcp0nh/1/). But the main problem is that scrollbar fades out too.

Is there a way to prevent scrollbar fading in such situation?

I found [another solution](http://lea.verou.me/2012/04/background-attachment-local/), which uses `background-attachment: local`, but in that example shadows are black and are naturally placed underneath list items. In my situation I need white fade in foreground

Answer (score -1):

From your example I see you know what is the width of the scroll bar, so my solution will be to change the width of the overlay from 100% to 100% - 5px, so the overlay will end before the scroll starts.

I removed the `width:100%` and added `left:0; right:5px` for both of the overlays.

[Here's the updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Girafa/vttcp0nh/1/)

Comment: I think, there would be entirely different approach. Something I'm doing is wrong.

Comment: @Girafa solved :) to work in all browsers you should put a scroll on container not on the list. Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vttcp0nh/5/

Comment: no. The bottom fade scrolls with the list. And always stays above the 4th element. But it has to be always at the bottom of visible area.

Comment: @Girafa then simply put those overlays on `ul`, not on .container http://jsfiddle.net/vttcp0nh/6/

Comment: no. Now fades are always near the first and last list elements.

Comment: If it's not to much you could add another container, as bis as the first one and put the fades on that, and keep the scroll on the first one.

Comment: I think the problem will remain as the new container will has more z-index than the first one. I think the problem is only resolvable by using js scrollbars, because they can be placed globally outside of the list scope and with their own z-index which would be more than fades has.

Comment: You are right, I have tried more solutions witch don't seem to work. At least with a custom scrollbar everything will look the same on any browser. I have used mCustomScrollbar on some projects by now and I would recommend it to anyone