# Add a fading effect at the bottom of a scroll view

Tags: html, css

I create a scroll view with some text on it. I want to create a fade effect at the bottom of the text. I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162283/css-how-to-make-scrollable-list-fading) an tried to implement it in my example that you can see on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbofsxzp/4/). The fade is not fixed on the bottom of the scroll view and the color is not really transparent. Do you have an idea about the problem?

this is my code

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 50px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.scrollviewwrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;              
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 30px; 
  overflow: scroll;
}

.scrollviewwrapper:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0), #fff);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change a few things:

- Since your current background color is `rgba(0,0,0,0.7)` ( a dark gray), which translates into the solid color of `#4c4c4c`  (or `rgba(76,76,76,1)`), you need to use it in your gradient so it blends in.
- i also had to make the `.overlay` element the reference for `.scrollviewwrapper`'s after (by removing the `position` from `.scrollviewwrapper`), to prevent the pseudo-element from scrolling together with its parent content. I also had to add `box-sizing:border-box` to it so it includes padding in its size.

See it working:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);
this.title_element = jQuery('.scrollviewwrapper', this.$el);

this.title_element.html('<ul>\r<li>Fermentum congue dictumst integer sapien conubia, per volutpat a duis donec, habitasse quisque tristique hac</li>\r<li>Imperdiet aliquam praesent id viverra aliquam inceptos</li>\r<li>Cubilia litora placerat fusce vulputate habitant varius cursus molestie lorem magna mi non</li>\r<li>Imperdiet sociosqu aenean ornare sagittis faucibus in facilisis vitae, lobortis curae hac justo tellus tincidunt</li>\r<li>Urna eu consequat non consectetur duis ut justo eleifend sapien</li>\r</ul> <ul>\r<li>Fermentum congue dictumst integer sapien conubia, per volutpat a duis donec, habitasse quisque tristique hac</li>\r<li>Imperdiet aliquam praesent id viverra aliquam inceptos</li>\r<li>Cubilia litora placerat fusce vulputate habitant varius cursus molestie lorem magna mi non</li>\r<li>Imperdiet sociosqu aenean ornare sagittis faucibus in facilisis vitae, lobortis curae hac justo tellus tincidunt</li>\r<li>Urna eu consequat non consectetur duis ut justo eleifend sapien</li>\r</ul> ');

function keyDownTextField(e) {
alert(document.getElementById('scrollviewwrapper').scrollTop);
var keyCode = e.keyCode;

  if(keyCode==38) {
  // up arrow

  } else if(keyCode==40) {
 // down arrow
  }
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 190px;
  width: 500px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.scrollviewwrapper {
  top: 0;              
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 30px; 
  overflow: auto;
  color: white;
  height: 190px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.scrollviewwrapper:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 21px);
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(76,76,76,0),  rgba(76,76,76,1));
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="scrollviewwrapper" id="scrollviewwrapper">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
```

Note I also added a negative left margin to the `:after` pseudo element and I changed the overflow of `.scrollviewwrapper` to `auto` so it only displays a vertical scrollbar, if the contents needs it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the pseudo element to `.overlay` instead:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);
this.title_element = jQuery('.scrollviewwrapper', this.$el);

this.title_element.html('<ul>\r<li>Fermentum congue dictumst integer sapien conubia, per volutpat a duis donec, habitasse quisque tristique hac</li>\r<li>Imperdiet aliquam praesent id viverra aliquam inceptos</li>\r<li>Cubilia litora placerat fusce vulputate habitant varius cursus molestie lorem magna mi non</li>\r<li>Imperdiet sociosqu aenean ornare sagittis faucibus in facilisis vitae, lobortis curae hac justo tellus tincidunt</li>\r<li>Urna eu consequat non consectetur duis ut justo eleifend sapien</li>\r</ul> <ul>\r<li>Fermentum congue dictumst integer sapien conubia, per volutpat a duis donec, habitasse quisque tristique hac</li>\r<li>Imperdiet aliquam praesent id viverra aliquam inceptos</li>\r<li>Cubilia litora placerat fusce vulputate habitant varius cursus molestie lorem magna mi non</li>\r<li>Imperdiet sociosqu aenean ornare sagittis faucibus in facilisis vitae, lobortis curae hac justo tellus tincidunt</li>\r<li>Urna eu consequat non consectetur duis ut justo eleifend sapien</li>\r</ul> ');

function keyDownTextField(e) {
  alert(document.getElementById('scrollviewwrapper').scrollTop);
  var keyCode = e.keyCode;

  if (keyCode == 38) {
    // up arrow

  } else if (keyCode == 40) {
    // down arrow
  }
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 50px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.overlay::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.scrollviewwrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="scrollviewwrapper" id="scrollviewwrapper">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```